# Kafka vs SignalR

Tags: azure, apache-kafka, signalr

I am a little bit confused on the roles played by Kafka and SignalR with regards to real time communication. Can somebody help me by providing insights whether Kafka can be used as a like to like replacement for SignalR or are they complementary?

Thanks and Regards,
Nagarajan B P

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Kafka aims to provide streaming data between many different programs. SignalR aims to provide real time communication between a client and server. So if you have a web app, thanks to cross scripting prevention, that page can only talk to its own server. But if you have many of your own custom services that don't all need to go through one point, Kafka would be more appropriate.

Answer (score 8):

SignalR is a library that simplifies the process of adding real-time web functionality to applications using WebSockets.

Kafka is an open source software which provides a framework for storing, reading and analysing streaming data.

You can use both if you want, using kafka as the entry point for events, and SignalR to notify web/mobile apps in real time.